# GitLab CI with Django project and MS SQL Database cannot login

Tags: python, sql-server, django, linux, gitlab-ci

Have the following .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: python:latest
    stages:
    - test

services:
    - name: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
      alias: mssql

variables:
    ACCEPT_EULA: Y
    SA_PASSWORD: ${SA_PASSWORD}
    MSSQL_PID: Developer
    MSSQL_HOST: mssql
    SECRET_KEY: ${SECRET_KEY}
    DEBUG: "True"
    DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
    DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
    DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    DB_HOST: mssql
    DB_PORT: 1433

# This folder is cached between builds
# http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#cache
cache:
    paths:
        - ~/.cache/pip/

before_script:
    - python -V
    - apt-get update -y && apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends curl gcc g++ gnupg 
      unixodbc-dev python3-dev npm nodejs
    - curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key 
      > add -
    - curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list         
      /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends -- 
      allow-unauthenticated msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
    - echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
    - echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
    - pip install -r requirements.txt

test:
    script:
        - python manage.py makemigrations
        - python manage.py migrate
        - python manage.py createsuperuser --username tester --email 
          tester@email.com --noinput
        - python manage.py loaddata
        - python manage.py collectstatic
        - python manage.py test --keepdb
```

With following error:

```
django.db.utils.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC 
Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 
'<my-username>'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Anyone have a solution, made various changes all with the same error.

UPDATE:
Have made changes to the .gitlab-ci.yml which has resolved the: "Login timeout expired" error, now getting: "Login failed for user my-username"

Comment: Given the reference to `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest` it looks like you're running up SQL Server in a Docker container. SQL Server doesn't start instantly, having to check/upgrade database file versions, rollback partial transactions, etc., before it is ready to accept connections. Have you tried putting a retry loop with delays on your code that's failing to connect?

Comment: For a concept example see [Seeding with test data on Web application startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/database-server-container#seeding-with-test-data-on-web-application-startup)

Comment: @ user15659931  did you find any solution for this?